# Why is u'(t)/u(t) = (ln(u(t)))'?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I saw this from [these online notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx) about differential equations.

> $\frac{\mu'(t)}{\mu(t)} = p(t)$
>
> Hopefully you will recognize the left side of this from your Calculus I class as the following derivative.
>
> ($\ln\mu(t))' = p(t)$

I don't think I understand why $\frac{\mu'(t)}{\mu(t)} = (\ln\mu(t))'$ is true. Why is this the case? Thank you very much!

Comment: Two words: chain rule.

Comment: Recall that the chain rule yields that $\frac{d}{dt} f(g(t)) = f'(g(t))*g'(t)$. In your case, we'll call $f(t) = \text{ln} (t)$ and let $g(t) = \mu (t)$

Comment: Oh okay, that makes perfect sense now! I forgot to try the chain rule. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the chain rule $$(\ln(f(x))'=\frac{1}{f(x)}\cdot f'(x)$$ for $$f(x)>0$$

Answer (score 0):

Apply chain rule :
$$(\ln( u(t))'=\frac {d}{dt} \ln (u(t))=\frac {d \ln u}{du}\frac {du}{dt}=\frac 1 {u(t)}\frac {du}{dt}=\frac {u'}{u}$$

Answer (score 0):

If we let $$I=\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx$$
then we can use substitution $u=f(x) \therefore dx=\frac{du}{f'(x)}$
so the integral becomes:
$$I=\int\frac{1}{u}du=ln|u|=ln|f(x)|+C \therefore \frac{d}{dx}\left[\ln(f(x))\right]=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$